# CQRS Matching Events and Commands

Tags: .net, cqrs, event-sourcing

I'm getting started with CQRS and I'm finding that my Event class definitions match my Command definitions almost 1 to 1. Aside from the obvious code repetition, I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong. There are certainly some cases where the events don't match the commands....but not many.

Take the simple CUD scenario:

Command Classes:

- CreatePost
- UpdatePost
- DeletePost

Event Classes:

- CreatedPost
- UpdatedPost
- DeletedPost

Any advice on this?

I'm using an event store, if that makes any difference.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you expand on this *I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong.* Why do you think there's something wrong?

Comment: Because it seems like I'm completely duplicating code with little benefit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You wouldn't normally use CQRS for CRUD scenarios. There are way simpler tools and patterns to create CRUDy applications.

CQRS brings many advantages to behavior-rich scenarios, where the verbs are not *Create, Read, Update, Delete*, but rather resemble real behavior. Like *PromoteEmployee* or *BlacklistVendor*.

Once you start modelling a behavior-rich domain, there might still be many corelating commands/events - which isn't a bad thing -, but you will also find that commands and the resulting events can be very different both in size (data contained) and in numbers.

Comment: I used the above as a trivial example. The CUD operations above are part of a larger bounded context that include more complex commands as well. Even there, I'm finding that my Events are mostly repetitions of my commands.

Comment: @Jeff still that's not a bad thing. You want that something happens (command), then it happened (event). In many cases this kind of duplication is just a reflection of reality. And introducing something like re-use wouldn't make any sense in this case, because it would contradict the idea of decoupling the parts of your system.

Comment: @Jeff it's unfortunate you chose CRUD as your example, that really derailed the conversation.

Answer (score 1):

To add a little to Dennis Traub's answer, CQRS extends past how you structure your code into the realm of the specs, namely how the UI works.  Point being not all UI's are CQRS-friendly; you want something more along the lines of [Task-based-UI's rather than CRUD-y UI's](http://cqrs.wordpress.com/documents/task-based-ui/).

Start with CRUD-y UI's and you may find yourself frustrated when applying CQRS.